# Power BI - Comparing an overall Value with a Sliced Value

Tags: powerbi

I am building a report of survey results based on survey questions that are answered on an scale from Strongly Agree - Strongly Disagree.  For each question I am showing a card that indicates the overall percentage of answers that are either "Agree" or "Strongly Agree".  Easy enough.

I also have several slicers in my report, and as expected, when a value is selected in a slicer, the card value changes to show the percentage of answers that are either "Agree" or "Strongly Agree" for just that "slice" of the population.  However, I would like to be able to compare that sliced value to the overall value dynamically using a second card that shows the +/- vs. the overall value.

Lets say the overall (unsliced) value on the card is 75.00% - When I apply a slicer, the value of card #1 changes to 68.00%, I would like the value of card  #2 to read -7%.  How can I reference the "sliced" value to subtract it from the overall (unsliced) value?  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use the ALL function to calculate the overall value and then subtract the value as it is filtered by your slicer.